# Getting infinite line output when returing object from rest-controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have been working on indiviual project and unable to fix this error.

I am new to Spring boot and rest controller. it's giving infinite output when i return my Product entity from RestController to my postman. please provide me some suggestion.

I am using mysql database

```
package com.example.hackernews.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class  Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column (name="price")
    Interger price;


    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @ManyToOne
    Customer customer;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Interger price ) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer ) {
        this.customer = customer;

    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You code does not compile, @MantToOne is a typing error. Please provide real code that compiles, and the code of your Customer and controller

Comment: what is @MantToOne in your code? typo?

Comment: Have you tried using the ```@JsonManagedReference``` annotation at all?... Thought we could try ruling that one out first.

Comment: Do you have `Product` object in your `Customer` class with `@OneToMany` annotation? if yes it can be the problem, you can solve it by adding    `@JsonProperty(access = WRITE_ONLY)` in `Product` class on `Customer field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the 'JsonIgnore' annotation to prevent the error that you were getting. Check this code and let me know how it worked out.

package com.example.hackernews.entity;

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore; 

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name="price")
    Interger price;

    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    Customer customer;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 
    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Interger price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }


}
```

Comment: I think he does not want to remove data from the output, but want to detect where the infinite loop occurs...